# C# connection string to database.best practise?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, security

I always encounter a lot of tutorials on the web.

below is a connection string of a command button in visual c# to try if the connection is established or not.

My point here is that.Is it good enough to type the username & password in a program?
like this : username = root; password = admin . When it comes to security is it vulnerable?like SQL injection or whatsoever.

Is it right to code like that?

```
try
        {
            string myConnection = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = admin";

            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" SELECT * database.edate ;", myConn);

            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
            myConn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

For best flexibility you should store connection strings in Configuration file `App.config` of `Web.config`. There is a special section `ConnectionStrings` which holds key-value pairs of connection strings.

Security information stored in code can be compromised with code disassembling. Configuration files can be encrypted.

[Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: i view App.config. It just came up with xml code. Is there any tutorial for this.Because a lot of my friends use this kind of method and not realizing the security of their programs.

Comment: I've add config encryption tutorial to my answer

Comment: thanks Jesse. gotta study this cause i am more aware to security.

Answer (score 0):

If someone get a hold on your executable he can reverse engineer the password and user name.
If you store it in app.config it is even easier. 
Best way when you deal with SQL SERVER is windows authentication (if possible)
If you deal with mysql/oracle or if windows authentication is not an option, 
you should find a way to mask these name/password (you can use some kind of algorithm to create the real password from a "ciphered" text and run it in the program) - it can be reversed also , but with larger effoerts. better ways would be using some kind of certificate. I  haven't done it myself.

SQL  Injection is not relevant to connection string, it is more related to the way you pass parameters to your queries, and if you check user input before passing it (if you use string concatenations rather then safer methods)

Answer (score 0):

Establishing a connection in your program itself may not create problems for your application, but as a convention it is a good practise to initiate your connections using ConfigurationManager in code and establish connections to databases in .config file.

Moreover security can be provided to a .config file.

Answer (score 0):

Benefits of using Configuration (app.config or web.config)

1. You can enforce security to configurations
2. You configure connection string or other settings based on the environments using configuration transformations like (Web.QA.Config, Web.Production.Config etc) - Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx